# Remove null array before correct json in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to echo php array in json format in back-end. but when i print it, it shows

```
[][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
[][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
[][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
[][][][
{
"USER":"root",
"PID":"31692",
"PPID":"31691",
"ELAPSED":"00:05",
"VSZ":"1072408",
"%CPU":"6.2",
"STATE":"S",
"COMMAND":"\/opt\/iims_client\/utils\/nfstop --rpc --interval 60 --sample 2 --mount ALL\n"
},{
"USER":"ctxsrvr",
"PID":"29309",
"PPID":"5152",
"ELAPSED":"9-07:51:37",
"VSZ":"605648",
"%CPU":"0.3",
"STATE":"S",
"COMMAND":"\/opt\/Citrix\/VDA\/bin\/ctxgfx -session 87\n"
}]
```

, I do not need the null array before "USER", so how can I remove them? Thanks. Here is my code:

```
elseif(preg_match("/<toptenproc>/",$line)){

        $line=fgets($file,1024);
        $line=ltrim($line);
        $header=preg_split('/\s+/',$line);
        while(!((preg_match("/<\/toptenproc>/",$line)))){
            $line=fgets($file,1024);
            $line=ltrim($line);
            $vars=preg_split('/\s+/',$line,8);
            // echo $vars[5];
            array_push($result, array($header[0] => $vars[0], $header[1] => $vars[1], $header[2] => $vars[2], $header[3] => $vars[3], $header[4] => $vars[4], $header[5] => $vars[5], $header[6] => $vars[6], $header[7] => $vars[7]));
        }

    // $result = (object) array_filter((array) $result);
    echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Is it possible there is output somewhere else in your code? Those nulls shouldn't be coming from anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: @RichGoldMD each time the `elseif` is ran, it would echo an array, either empty, or with one one or more objects via the json_encode. The reason you see back to back `[][][][]` would be because the elseif is ran in a loop. I am guessing he's doing `$result = array();` each iteration and if his while loop fails in the code, he's just echoing `[]`.

Comment: Makes sense @Ultimater

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first regular expression checks for `<toptenproc>`
Your second regular expression checks for `</toptenproc>`

If the ending tag hasn't been encountered yet, you simply shouldn't be echoing anything. Your solution should be as simple as checking the array size before echoing anything:

```
if(count($result))
{
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Alternative, you can put a `$whileLoopRan = false;` before the loop,
then put a `$whileLoopRan = true;` inside the loop and preform the echo only when the loop ran. Some people prefer `$i++;` then use "i" instead, whatever floats your boat.

It's also possible, you're echoing too early and should do it outside the elseif, only after the loop finishes.

If you're trying to parse XML, you should be using an XML parser anyways, not regexp.

Answer (score 0):

use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

`array_filter($array); // it will remove null at the first depth`